# Can I export more than one default per module? React Project with Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

### **Failed to compile. Parsing error: Only one default export allowed per module.**

So I have User Auth set up with firebase in my react project, now I want to connect a DB.

Inside my firebase.js i have this code below:

```
import "firebase/auth";
import * as firebase from "firebase";

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyBR1E5loxQz_jA9YvG4HgNFq-nnHYunkkY",
    authDomain: "tryb-prints.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://tryb-prints.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "tryb-prints",
    storageBucket: "tryb-prints.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "333649716090",
    appId: "1:333649716090:web:27914b671376e870172cc3",
    measurementId: "G-YJG2RN7J95"
  };


const app = firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    databaseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
    projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    appId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID
})

//Initialize firebase
var fireDb = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export default fireDb.database().ref();
export const auth = app.auth;
export default app;
```

And it is throwing back this error! Now I understand why, but was wondering is there a way around this without creating a new module? Any help at all is greatly appricated! Thanks!

```
Failed to compile.

./src/firebase.js
  Line 32:1:  Parsing error: Only one default export allowed per module.

  30 | export default fireDb.database().ref();
  31 | export const auth = app.auth;
> 32 | export default app;
     | ^
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can export multiple from one file

```
export = {
   export_one,
   export_two,
   export_three,
}
```

or,

```
 export export_one
 export export_two
 ..........
```

But only one default export.

in your case you have two default export which deoen't work. Then import necessary modules like this:

```
import {export_one, export_two} from './folder_name/file_name'
```

Read [this](https://hackernoon.com/import-export-default-require-commandjs-javascript-nodejs-es6-vs-cheatsheet-different-tutorial-example-5a321738b50f) for more info